# "port 53: Address already in use" docker error when I run docker compose up command

Tags: android, flutter, dart, at-sign, at-platform

ERROR: for 515f8b2ecd33_docker-bind_bind_1 Cannot start service bind: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint docker-bind_bind_1 (bc8836ceccc907c7ad0610e941b533c68f250c56cffcd4646e9171e7a330c9b3): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address already in use'

Answer (score 0):

Comment out masqdns parts of the docker-compose.yaml file that you should have in virtual environment folder("Home/User/ve").

If  the  error still persist Please update your docker-compose.yaml file.